# Combobox TreeView dropdown

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, treeview

I am currently on the topic of creating a Combobox that expands with a full treeview where one can select a topic

It is for category selection.

The current approach just displays all "expanded" upfront with different margin depending on which level they are (utilized using itemcontainerstyle margin and a converter)

However, that is not what I want it to be as it tends to grows extremely large with larger category trees

Thus I am searching for other solutions

I could write a custom control but I also face issues in understanding how the selector controls actually get build

Thus my questions are:

- Is there a way to get a combobox having a treeview for selecting instead of an itemscontrol?
- If no, how to implement the selector properly (could also just derive from control and build it myself, but that would require more work and casting the control to selector etc. would not be possible --> some attached properties are not working then)

Comment: Can I ask the requirement behind the drop down portion of the treeview?  Is it to ensure only one item is selected?  To save screen real estate?  The built in tree is not too complicated in wpf.  If you really need to stick with this design creating your own control would not be too difficult... I wouldn't necessarily say you need to derive from the Selector class.  It is not wrong to make your own custom control and have it's own dependency properties to retrieve the selected item from.

Comment: Pretty much to save screen space and for the user to see at glance in which category a given item is without navigating through the whole tree. Deriving from selector is not mandatory but would be kinda nice as it would work with the attached properties we already have out of the box. As also noted: no problem in creating the actual control but more in how to make it derive clean from selector (Google is not very helpful here..)